# File Upload is executing multiple times

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to create a form where by the user selects a location where they then upload a document using `CFFILE ACTION ="UPLOAD"`. I am not great at this so any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code. Essentially, there is a dropdown list of folder locations. The user first selects one of the locations. Then clicks 'browse' to choose a file. Finally they click submit and the file uploads.

The code that is `#dir#` is the folder location that is linked to each of the location names. What is happening at the moment is that the document gets uploaded successfully... but it is uploading to all the folder locations instead of the one that is selected from the dropdown. Here is my code:

**docuploads.cfm**

```
<cfquery name="getLocation">
    SELECT *
    FROM Locations
    ORDER BY FolderName
</cfquery>

<form action="docuploads.cfm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_form" id="upload_form"> 
    <select name="folderID">
        <option value="">--- Select Folder ---</option>
        <cfoutput query="getLocation">
            <option value="#FolderName#"">#FolderName#</option>
        </cfoutput>
    </select>

    <cfoutput query="getLocation">
       <CFIF IsDefined("form.upload_now")>
          <CFIF structKeyExists(form, "ul_path") and len(form["ul_path"])>
             <CFFILE ACTION="UPLOAD" FILEFIELD="ul_path" 
                    DESTINATION="C:\Documents\#dir#\"         
                    NAMECONFLICT="OverWrite">
              <CFSET ClientFilePath = "#clientDirectory#\#clientFile#">
          </CFIF>
      </CFIF>
     </CFOUTPUT>

     <br /><br />
     Click on the Browse button to select the file to Upload:<br>
     <input type="file" name="ul_path" id="ul_path" style="height: 22px;width: 350px;" value=""><br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="upload_now" id="upload_now" value="Submit" style="height: 22px;">
     <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear" style="height: 22px;">
     <br /><br /><br />
</form>
```

I hope this makes some sense - can anyone shed any light on getting this to work?

Comment: The upload is inside a `<cfoutput query="">` which is a loop, and that's why it's uploading to every location. You'll want to pull the `<cffile>` out of that block and specify `#dir#` from the user's selection.

Comment: if that is the complete code, then well the looping is 1 issue, but the undeclared variables will cause more errors.

Comment: Those variables *are* defined - in the `cffile` scope. See [Evaluating Unscoped Variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fdf.html). @Jen - That said, you should really scope to avoid unintended naming conflicts. Also, you typically want to use the `serverXXX` variables ie `cffile.serverFile`,`cffile.serverDirectory` (not client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you didnt post the complete code because your `#clientDirectory#/#clientFile#` don't seem to have a source in your code above.

I put together a possible sample of what It may look like.  I also moved your upload routine from the body of your code to the top for readability.

```
<CFIF IsDefined("form.upload_now")>
    <CFIF structKeyExists(form, "ul_path") and len(form["ul_path"])>

        <!--- assuming you need to lookup info from the database --->   
        <cfquery name="getThisLocation">
            SELECT FolderID, FolderName, dir 
            FROM Locations
            where foldername=#form.folderid#

        </cfquery>      


        <CFFILE ACTION="UPLOAD" FILEFIELD="ul_path" 
                    DESTINATION="C:\Documents\#getThisLocation.dir#\"         
                    NAMECONFLICT="OverWrite">

        <CFSET ClientFilePath = "#getThisLocation.clientDirectory#\##getThisLocation.clientFile#">

     </CFIF>
</CFIF>


<cfquery name="getLocation">
    SELECT *
    FROM Locations
    ORDER BY FolderName
</cfquery>

<form action="docuploads.cfm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_form" id="upload_form"> 

<CFIF IsDefined("form.upload_now")>
    <CFIF structKeyExists(form, "ul_path") and len(form["ul_path"])>
    <P>FILE UPLOADED</P>
    </CFIF>
</CFIF>

    <select name="folderID">
        <option value="">--- Select Folder ---</option>
        <cfoutput query="getLocation">
            <option value="#FolderName#"">#FolderName#</option>
        </cfoutput>
    </select>



     <br /><br />
     Click on the Browse button to select the file to Upload:<br>
     <input type="file" name="ul_path" id="ul_path" style="height: 22px;width: 350px;" value=""><br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="upload_now" id="upload_now" value="Submit" style="height: 22px;">
     <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear" style="height: 22px;">
     <br /><br /><br />
</form>
```

I also added a snippet of code to let the user know that the file has been uploaded.

Comment: Hi Steve - the code you have provided has been extremely helpful. THANK YOU! The issue seems to be with -  

    where foldername=#form.foldername# - as I get undefined errors. When I define it with  - <CFIF NOT isDefined("folderName")>
 <CFSET folderName = "">
</CFIF>
   It still doesn't help.
When I change it, the page works but the document is only uploading to the first selection - when I choose one of the other locations, no dice. :(

Comment: Try this: rename your select box from folderID to foldername.  Is that where you are storing your path?  I was under the impression that  your folderID value was a primary key value from a database table that listed the paths inside of it.  That is why I have the query at the top. I thought you needed to lookup your path.  If you are storing your full path inside folderid, then you can just reference that.

Comment: In my database I have FolderID (primary key), Folder Name (the name), dir (the path eg /alldocs/training/) 

I am guessing this just can't be done. I am still getting - Element READTITLE is undefined in FORM.  
 
  
The error occurred in 
 
26 :     SELECT *
27 :     FROM Reads
28 :     WHERE folderName=#form.folderName#

Comment: Thank you for all your help - it has been much appreciated - this stuff is so frustrating. :(

Comment: Hi, I updated my code a little to reflect the form variables and database variables being used.  As for the error your getting "form.readtitle", you must have additional code not mentioned in your original posting.  Sounds like your just missing a text box on your form.

Comment: Steve - I just wanted to say thank you very much for all of your help with this code! Wishing you a wonderful weekend. Thanks again!! :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
<CFIF IsDefined("form.upload_now")>
      <CFIF structKeyExists(form, "ul_path") and len(form["ul_path"])>
         <CFFILE ACTION="UPLOAD" FILEFIELD="#form.ul_path#" 
                DESTINATION="C:\Documents\#dir#\"         
                NAMECONFLICT="OverWrite">
          <CFSET ClientFilePath = "#clientDirectory#\#clientFile#">
      </CFIF>
      <cfoutput>file uploaded successfully</cfoutput>
  </CFIF>

<cfquery name="getLocation">
  SELECT *
  FROM Locations
  ORDER BY FolderName
</cfquery>

<form action="docuploads.cfm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_form" id="upload_form"> 
  <select name="folderID">
    <option value="">--- Select Folder ---</option>
    <cfoutput query="getLocation">
        <option value="#FolderName#"">#FolderName#</option>
    </cfoutput>
</select>

  <br /><br />
 Click on the Browse button to select the file to Upload:<br>
 <input type="file" name="ul_path" id="ul_path" style="height: 22px;width: 350px;" value=""><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="upload_now" id="upload_now" value="Submit" style="height: 22px;">
 <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear" style="height: 22px;">
 <br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for responding. The code works great if I manually have the destination path entered but it does not pick up the path from the DB. Hmmm! Thank you so much again!